# Enable HTTPS on Knative serving

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, istio, knative-serving

Hello I have deployed an EKS cluster with my app running in it, under  **serving.knative.dev/route=helloworld-go** I have also configured EKS ELB with ACM but still routes showing http on kubectl, Is it neccessary to configure knative serving with letsencrypt for pods to make them https, after we already setup the ELB with ACM

[image: first image]

Answer (score 4):

> Is it neccessary to configure knative serving with letsencrypt for pods to make them https, after we already setup the ELB with ACM

Not really. Just the communication from your ELBs to the K8s endpoint of your Knative function will go through HTTP.

[image]

Not that you can't use letsencrypt, just keep in mind that letsencrypt will not work if you don't externally expose the service requesting the cert or publicly expose your domain because letsencrypt needs to [send a challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/) to verify that you actually own the domain.

✌️

Comment: I have already configured EKS ELB with ACM but still domain is not working with HTTPS, it is only opening in HTTP.

Comment: Is knative tied to directly to the K8s service that created the load balancer?

Comment: It is solved, Just changed the protocol from TCP to HTTP

Comment: Awesome great to hear.